# Ant XMLTask cannot insert new xml node into existing XML file

Tags: xml, xpath, ant

I'm just trying to copy one node from an existing file and paste it into another file. Nothing fancy. I also have some code to insert the node to see if I could get it to do that but I failed rather gloriously :) Any help would be greatly appreciated

Base XML File: (input.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <bar>
        <tests>
            <test id="1"/>
            <test id="2"/>
        </tests>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

The ant targets I'm running:

```
<target name="copy">
    <xmltask source="input.xml" dest="1.xml">
        <copy path="/foo/bar/tests/test[@id='1']" buffer="storedXml" />
    </xmltask>
</target>

<target name="paste-xml" depends="define-tasks,copy">
    <xmltask source="input.xml" dest="output.xml">
        <insert path="/foo/bar/tests/test[last()]" file="output.xml" buffer="storedXml"/>
    </xmltask>
</target>

<target name="insert-xml" depends="define-tasks">
    <xmltask source="input.xml" dest="output.xml">
        <insert path="/foo/bar/tests/test[last()]" file="output.xml">
            <![CDATA[
            <test id="3"/>
            ]]>
        </insert>
    </xmltask>
</target>

<target name="write-config" depends="define-tasks">
    <delete file="output.xml" failonerror="false"/>
    <echoxml file="output.xml">
        <foo>
            <bar>
                <tests/>
            </bar>
        </foo>
    </echoxml>
</target>
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any question ?... Please, provide the seconf XML document, into which you have to insert "the" node from the first XML document. Please, specify which exactly node from the first document must be inserted into the second documet. Please, specify where exactly in the second document should the node be inserted.

Comment: Also, what does this question have to do with XPath? Inserting a node into an XML document cannot be done with XPath, which is a query language (only) for XML documents and as such cannot create/modify xml documents.

Comment: The XMLTask for ant uses Xpath notation. If you look at the write-config target you can see there that a file is getting created called output.xml which has the xml in it. The node i'm trying to insert is <test id="3"/> I would expect the output to look something like this:        <foo>
            <bar>
                <tests><test id="3"/></tests>
            </bar>
        </foo>

Comment: OK, My guess is that you should remove the CDATA -- its contents is just text that looks like an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. The issue was I was setting the output file in the xmltask and the file attribute in the insert node. The file attribute in the insert node is when you want to insert an entire xml file into the destination attribute of the xmltask.

Not Tested code but something like this should work now:

```
<target name="paste-xml" depends="define-tasks,copy">
    <xmltask source="input.xml" dest="output.xml">
        <insert path="/foo/bar/tests/test[last()]" buffer="storedXml"/>
    </xmltask>
</target>

<target name="insert-xml" depends="define-tasks">
    <xmltask source="input.xml" dest="output.xml">
        <insert path="/foo/bar/tests/test[last()]">
            <![CDATA[
            <test id="3"/>
            ]]>
        </insert>
    </xmltask>
</target>
```

Comment: I tried this, but seems the output.xml is wrong


      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
      <foo>
       <bar>
        <tests>
         <test id="1"/>
         <test id="2">
          <test id="3"/>
         </test>
        </tests>
       </bar>
      </foo>

Comment: The proper syntax is most likely: <insert path="/foo/bar/tests/test[last()]" position="after">  (by default the position in UNDER the selected node)